# Accessing the Members of a tm struct When Using localtime_s

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I'm trying to use the following code to return the time in the format HH:MM:SS. I was previously using `localtime` however given this is depreciated and figured I'd switch to `localtime_s` like so:

```
time_t t;
struct tm now;
localtime_s(&now, &t);
std::string stimeNow = std::to_string(now->tm_hour) + ":" + std::to_string(now->tm_min) +":" + std::to_string(now->tm_sec);
```

However MSVC uderlines `now->tm_hour`, `now->tm_min` and `now->tm_sec`, saying

```
Error: expression must have a pointer type
```

And when I compile it I recieve the following error:

```
error C2819: type 'tm' does not have an overloaded member 'operator ->'
```

I'm pretty inept with pointers and structs so can someone tell me where I've gone wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: I've already tried this, although it compiles MSVC still underlines the statements and it returns -1:-1:-1.

Comment: You need to initialize `t` before using it or pass `nullptr` instead.

Answer (score 0):

An example of its usage is below :

```
/* localtime example */
  #include <stdio.h>      /* puts, printf */
  #include <time.h>       /* time_t, struct tm, time, localtime */

int main ()
{
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    time (&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);
    printf ("Current local time and date: %s", asctime(timeinfo));
    return 0;
  }
```

By the way you can disable deprecated warnings(errors) in VS by adding the following code to your source file :

```
#pragma warning (disable : <The error or warning code it gives when you use the unsafe version>)
```

Comment: If you read the question, you'll see that I'm trying to **avoid** `localtime`